# Searching MySQL database using volley

Tags: php, android, mysql

I tried retrieving all data from a MySQL database using php and was sucessful in doing so in my app. Now I tried using an edittext to pass that string to the php but I am unable to do so. I was sucessful but without using the volley library. Is there any way to add a "keyword" after the url using volley, since that is the only thing I need for this to work?
In the previous version I used `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search, "GET", params);` to pass the params to the php..

Example and code:
I want this to be passed as url string: `http://myip/myproject/search.php?keyword .`

I'm using this code, like usually:
on the edittext field -> searchIntent.putExtra("keyword",txtkeyword.getText().toString());

In my search activity:

```
public class AllEmpresasActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AllEmpresasActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Empresas json url
    private static final String url = "http://192.168.1.90/android_connect/search.php?params=%1$s,num1";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Empresa> empresaList = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public String searchkey;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_empresas);

        Intent searchIntent = getIntent();
        searchkey = searchIntent.getStringExtra("keyword");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, empresaList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
                                empresa.setMarca(obj.getString("marca"));
                                empresa.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("imagempequena"));
                                empresa.setMarcatotal(obj.getString("marcatotal"));
                                empresa.setDatainicio(obj.getString("datainicio"));
                                empresa.setActividade(obj.getString("actividade"));

                                // adding empresa to empresa array
                                empresaList.add(empresa);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AllEmpresasActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private static final String sUrl = "http://myip/myproject/search.php?keyword=%1$s";
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        String searchKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyword");
        String url = String.format(sUrl, searchKey);
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        ...
```

Comment: I accepted the aswer too soon. The keyword is not being passed to the php.

Comment: http://localhost/android_connect/search.php?keyword=ez, for example, should only desplay one result as in the browser. typing ez in my edit text field and passing it to the relevant activity, displays all results in my database thus the php script is not getting the keyword. ( $keyword=$_GET["keyword"]; )

Comment: than you should use the following url http://myip/myproject/search.php?keyword=%1$s instead of the one you provided in the question

Comment: That is absolutely correct. My bad for not interpreting the response correctly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code like follows according to what i understood from u

```
private static final String url = "http://****/get_items.php?keyword=%1$s";
String searchKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("2");
        Final_url = String.format(url, searchKey);
```

when i print the Final_url like this

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"url "+ Final_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the printed value is always

```
http://*****/get_items.php?keyword=null
```

Is There Something I'm Missing ?